# Asymptotic freedom of the $\phi^4$ theory depending on spacetime dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, spacetime-dimensions, effective-field-theory

I heard that $\phi^4$ theory in $4-$dimensions is NOT asymptotically free.

But in lower dimensions like $2$ and $3$, it is said to be asymptotically free.

However, what confuses me is that in $3-$dimensions, $\phi^4$ theory is said to be asymptotically free "only" on a speicific trajectory in the renormalization group.

So, I look for clarifications on the following issues:

1. Exactly in what sense is the $\phi^4$ theory in $4-$dimensions NOT asymptotically free?
2. In $2,3-$dimensions, in what exact sense is the theory said to be asymptotically free?

What is certain is that $\phi^4$ theory has been rigorously constructed in $2,3-$dimensions as a nontrivial interacting theory while it is believed to be trivial in $4-$dimensions. Moreover, Borel summability of the perturbative expansion for certain physical quantities was proven in $2,3-$dimensions.

I would like to know the relationship between these issues and asymptotic freedom.

I deeply appreciate any clarification.

Comment: This is just an exercise in computing beta functions. Asymptotic freedom means $\beta(0) = 0$ and $\beta(g + \delta g) < 0$. The need for a specific trajectory occurs when there are relevant operators... in this case $\phi^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by relelvant operators? and $\phi^2$??

Comment: If you know what $\phi^4$ is, you should know what $\phi^2$ is. Relevant operators (those with dimension $ < d$) are crucial to be able to make sense of what a trajectory in the renormalization group is. Most textbooks should cover them.